# Эмуляция ввода текста, независимости от раскладки в python

Tags: python

Как можно реализовать ввод текста независимо от раскладки. Т.е - ввели World, переключились на русскую раскладку, и все равно получилось World.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так не бывает . Можно просто "programmatically " 
менять раскладку.AppleScript:

```
on switchToInputSource(name)
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
        tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description is "text input")
            # !! Sadly, we must *visibly* select (open) the text-input menu-bar extra in order to
            # !! populate its menu with the available input sources.
            select
            tell menu 1
                # !! Curiously, using just `name` instead of `(get name)` didn't work: 'Access not allowed'.
                click (first menu item whose title = (get name))
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end switchToInputSource

my switchToInputSource("English")
```

Потом вызываешь это из питона :

```
import os
os.system("osascript -e '<there applescript is going>'")
```

Это для мака.На винде не знаю как.

Это от сюда:[Change Keyboard Layout Programmatically - StackOverflow in English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729704/change-osx-keyboard-layoutinput-source-programmatically-via-terminal-or-appl)